# how use Excel COM add-in a VSTO add-in without installing visual studio

Tags: vsto, excel-addins

how do I get my vsto to work on Excel without the settings of Visual Studio? im trying to add not valid. can you help me a solution for that

the file that I have

Comment: Do you want to install it on another machine?

Comment: im finis. clear. for problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to distribute a VSTO add-in, the target machines will need the VSTO runtime.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217